# how to query to get an ordered result from cassandra table

Tags: cassandra

i need to query like:

```
select * from items where group="a" order by update_time desc;
```

however,the column "update_time" of each row will not be fixed,it will change as we need.
so,how can i design the cassandra tables to achieve the goal : querying to get an ordered result?

i need to query like:

```
select * from items where group="a" order by update_time desc;
```

however,the column "update_time" of each row will not be fixed,it will change as we need.
so,how can i design the cassandra tables to achieve the goal : querying to get an ordered result?

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Table**

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    ItemA text,
    update_time timeuuid,
    ItemB int,
    PRIMARY KEY ( ItemA, update_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (update_time DESC);
```

**Ordering Field should be part of clustering key.**

```
Please refer the above table, where we ordering the rows update_time as Desending order.
```